# Hadoop input split (MapV1)

Tags: hdfs

Problem : What is input split

- How the input split is calculated in MapReduce v1?
- Is the input  Split is same as the HDFS block size?

Comment: Please use Google for that. SO is not a place for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Each input split size generally equals to HDFS block size. For example, for a file of 1GB size, there will be 16 input splits, if block size is 64MB. However, split size can be configured to be less/more than HDFS block size. For general case, calculation of input splits is done with FileInputFormat.

Calculation of input split size is done in InputFileFormat as:

```
Math.max("mapred.min.split.size", Math.min("mapred.max.split.size", blockSize));
```

Some examples:

```
mapred.min.split.size   mapred.max.split.size   dfs.block.size  Split Size
1 (default)             Long.MAX_VALUE(default) 64MB(Default)   64MB
1 (default)             Long.MAX_VALUE(default) 128MB           128MB
128MB                   Long.MAX_VALUE(default) 64MB            128MB
1 (default)             32MB                    64MB            32MB
```

For detailed explanation, you can view [here](http://codinghassle.blogspot.com.tr/2014/06/hadoop-number-of-map-and-reduce-tasks.html).